# How to modify a schema.xml of an existing list

Tags: list-view

I have a solution deployed, with custom lists. And i would like to modify the schema.xml to have a new view, without deleting the list i already have.

I've first created the new views in the schema.xml of my list definitions, hoping that it would change the current instance of the list. But it didn't worked.

When i try to create a new view, i have the choice between creating a new view from an existing view (red in the picture), or from a view template (green in the picture).

That's a beginning. Maybe you know how I could access to this list view template with powershell or maybe how i could directly during my deployement modify the schema.xml ?

[Picture!](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=583252Sanstitre.png)
Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 3):

Any changes made to schema.xml after a list has been created from it. Will not work on the existing lists.

If you need to make changes to existing lists you have to do that using code (or UI)

Comment: Actually, that's not entirely correct. An IIS reset will propagate many changes to views, although I haven't tested whether it works to create new views in SP2010. See my Building the SharePoint User Experience book, page 152.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, Do you know how i could access to the template view though ? So that i could add it to my deployement script ? 
Thx

Comment: Yeah, this is not right. By my experience most if not all of the changes to schema.xml are reflected into existing list instances.